# String to Date Conversion throwing error in DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I've been stuck in this issue that when I convert my string in format (yyyy-mm-dd) to date it throws the following error - "This step results in a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode."

[image: The last column is the string that needs to converted to Date]

After I convert it to date by selecting the icon on the left of column name.

[image: This is error.]

I've spent too much time on this and going to Imprort mode is not an option for me. I need to do this in DirectQuery itself.

I've tried this by creating calculated fields in PowerBI and when I use DateValue function to convert the string to date it again throws a error.

Comment: Depending on the source, you may be able to [import using a native database query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-database-query). See also [Convert Column from Text to Number in Direct Query](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Convert-Column-from-Text-to-Number-in-Direct-Query/td-p/559321)